# why have my 8 BCH (bitcoin cash) disappeard

Tags: bitcoin-cash

I received 8 BCH after the fork and have had them in my Blockchain.com wallet in Settings-General, up to the 14th December, when I checked on the 15th December the BCH had gone with absolutely no reference to them, the wallet pages have been changed to show how many BCH you have as well as Bitcoins and Ether. there is now a page dedicated to getting started with BCH and what you can do with them but mine have gone. I have emailed Blockchain.com they don't reply. This has to be a cock up by the blockchain.com team as my BTC and Ether are all there. any one know what I can do please.

Comment: Was the 8 BCH on an imported address or was it part of the blockchain.com wallet?

Comment: Hi, Christian,  the 8 BCH were part of my blockchain.com wallet, just as they had appeared  as a bonus after the hard fork. I had not transferred them to any specific wallet address. They had always appeared in my wallet under Settings, General, there is no reference to BCH there any more. When I click on BCH on my home page it goes to a page that says I have no BCH, I have never received any BCH, and I have not transferred any BCH, My BCH have just disappeared without trace or record of transfer according to my wallet they never existed. What can I possibly do please.