# Where is my BCH - Blockchain wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, bitcoin-cash

I had a small amount of BTC before the fork in my Blockchain.info wallet. I got the same amount in BCH post fork. Up until Blockchain started accepting BCH in the main dashboard (November 2017?), I used to be able to see my BCH balance in the Settings menu. Post Blockchain accepting BCH in the main dashboard, my BCH balance seems to have disappeared from the Settings menu. I sent a ticket to Blockchain and have not had a reply in like 2 weeks.

Is anyone else having this problem? Any ideas how to get my BCH?

Thanks

Comment: Related https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/65591/why-have-my-8-bch-bitcoin-cash-disappeard